# Rails custom validation method is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to validate the input(text) of `answer text fields` There are four answer fields i have. Following are the validations i want to accomplish.

- if one answer field has decimal value than all four answer fields should also have decimal values.
- if answer fields has no difference or only 1 in answer fields numbers than error should be shown.i.e if answer1 field has number 10, answer2 field has 11 than error should display.

I have written following code but it doesn't run validation and i have noticed there is alot of duplication in my code. Can you plz look into the code and let me know why its not working.

```
validate :check_answer, :on => :create

def check_answer
a1 = answer_1.gsub(/[^\.\d+]/, '')
a2 = answer_2.gsub(/[^\.\d+]/, '')
a3 = answer_3.gsub(/[^\.\d+]/, '')
a4 = answer_4.gsub(/[^\.\d+]/, '')

if !(a1.empty?) || !(a2.empty?) || !(a3.empty?) || !(a4.empty?)
  if a1.include?('.') || a2.include?('.') || a3.include?('.') || a4.include?('.')
    errors.add :answer_choices, "should have decimal values." if a1.empty? || a2.empty? || a3.empty? || a4.empty?
  end
  a1 = a1.to_i
  a2 = a2.to_i
  a3 = a3.to_i
  a4 = a4.to_i
  if (a1 - a2 == 0..1) || (a1 - a3 == 0..1) || (a1 - a4 == 0..1)
    errors.add :answer_choices, "can't be too close in number range."
  elsif (a2 - a1 == 0..1) || (a2 - a3 == 0..1) || (a2 - a4 == 0..1)
    errors.add :answer_choices, "can't be too close in number range."
  elsif (a3 - a1 == 0..1) || (a3 - a2 == 0..1) || (a3 - a4 == 0..1)
    errors.add :answer_choices, "can't be too close in number range."
  elsif (a4 - a1 == 0..1) || (a4 - a2 == 0..1) || (a4 - a3 == 0..1)
    errors.add :answer_choices, "can't be too close in number range."
  end
end
end
```

Comment: above code of mine works after i restart the server. Apology for your time :(

Comment: DRY version of code is welcome and i'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for whether the result of the subtraction is less than a range. What you want is to check for whether the difference of the two numbers is within [-1, 1]:

```
if (-1..1).include?(a1 - a2) || (-1..1).include?(a1 - a3) || (-1..1).include?(a1 - a4)
  errors.add :answer_choices, "can't be too close in number range."
elsif (-1..1).include?(a2 - a3) || (-1..1).include?(a2 - a4)
  errors.add :answer_choices, "can't be too close in number range."
elsif (-1..1).include?(a3 - a4)
  errors.add :answer_choices, "can't be too close in number range."
end
```

Range objects have various built-in methods geared towards testing for inclusion, etc:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Range.html

Comment: I neglected to remove checks that were duplicates. I've corrected this now.